# Half gnome half unity 13.10

Tags: unity, gnome

After I installed gnome-shell, the unity desktop is half gnome.. I removed the gnome, but the problem exist.

I tried to reset unity, also tried to reinstall unity and nothing helps.. -

The screen of my problem:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`unity-tweak-tool`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/), you can change the theme, which is the problem, not the Gnome Desktop. The theme was installed as Gnome Desktop uses it by default. It is called 'Adwaita', the default theme for Unity is 'Ambiance'. You also need to go to <kbd>Window Controls</kbd>, and change it from 'right' to 'left'. Note that these change will affect Gnome as well.

[image: Adwaita]

[image: Ambiance]

No reinstalling required. You can even reinstall Gnome, if you like.